Retrieve an oidc access token from Nuxt 3 app
I tried to retrieve a simple token from an idp in my Nuxt 3 fresh app.
To do that I've created a vue page which calls my ssr API to get the token.
But when I call the idp I get a fetch failed response.
With my postman that work perfectly and I don't know why that doesn't work here.
I'm new in nuxt and oidc world. I surrely don't do something correctly but I don't know what... Maybe fetching method or I missing something in my header/body request?
EDITED
Here is my view page:
<h1>Home Page</h1>

  <div>
    <button @click="getToken">Get Token</button>
    <p>{{ token }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const token = ref(null);

const getToken = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await $fetch('/api/token');
    const data = await response.json();
    token.value = data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching token:', error);
  }
};
</script>

Here is my SSR api (server/api/token.js):
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

  try {
    const token  = await fetch (
        `https://.../token`,
        { 
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            } ,
            method : 'POST', 
            body : JSON.stringify({
                'client_id': "****",
                'client_secret': "****",
                'grant_type': "password",
                'username': "****",
                'password': "****",
            })
        }
      );

    return token;
  
  } catch (error) {

      console.log(error);
    sendError(event, createError({
      statusCode: 500,
      statusMessage: 'Internal Server Error: ',
      data: {
          error: error.message,
          stack: error.stack,
      }
    }));
  }

})

I have now a Missing form parameter: grant_type
Error 400 : 
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Missing form parameter: grant_type"
}

body content:   {"client_id":"****","client_secret":"****","grant_type":"password","username":"****","password":"****"}

Which fetch fails - the one from your frontend to the backend, or the one made from the backend to the external endpoint?

You are logging error information both in the backend and the frontend. What did that actually result in?

The backend one fetch failed.
"data Object { error: "fetch failed", stack: "TypeError: fetch failed\n at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13178:13\n at async Object.handler..."

You are not specifying a Content-Type in that request, why not? (And if headers :event.node.req.headers was supposed to "pass on" the request headers from the client(?), application/x-www-form-urlencoded would surely not match the type of content you are sending there.)

Why that doesn't match with my type of content ? For a POST request we need to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded right ?

No, of course you don't need to use that particular one, just because the request method is POST. form-urlencoded means a body content of the form parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&... - and your JSON.stringify result of course does not have that format. You are sending JSON, so the content type should be application/json.

I finally get the token by using URLSearchParams and set again application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of using JSON.stringify with application/json.
I don't undestand why with application/json I got an Invalid request : Missing form parameter: grant_type that I was correctly set in the body.
Here is my final code to retrieve the token :
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  try {
    const token  = await fetch(`https://****/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token`,
      { 
        method : 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
          'client_id': "****",
          'client_secret': "****",
          'grant_type': "password",
          'username': "****",
          'password': "****"
        })
      });

    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    sendError(event, createError({
      statusCode: 500,
      statusMessage: 'Internal Server Error: ',
      data: {
          error: error.message,
          stack: error.stack,
      }
    }));
  }

})

Thanks to @C3roe to help me to understand my problem.
